# rails 3, xml formatting and builder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, builder

I have an xml tag that needs to be formatted like so:

```
<AddDealRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

I can't seem to get this to work properly, using builder.  I am attempting the following code in builder:

```
xml.AddDealRequest(:xmlns:xsi => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", :xmlns:xsd => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ) do
```

but obviously that second colon is throwing off the symbol.  Is there any way to escape that second symbol? Or is this declaration entirely necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting your symbols:

```
xml.AddDealRequest(
    :'xmlns:xsi' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    :'xmlns:xsd' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
)
```

You could also try using strings instead of symbols

```
xml.AddDealRequest(
    'xmlns:xsi' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
    'xmlns:xsd' => "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
)
```

but I don't know if builder will be happy with that but the [documentation includes things like this](http://builder.rubyforge.org/classes/Builder/XmlMarkup.html):

```
xm.target("name"=>"compile", "option"=>"fast")
# => <target option="fast" name="compile"\>
```

so strings for the attribute names should work.

A bit of time in `irb` might be help clarify things:

```
>> 'where_is:pancakes_house'.to_sym
=> :"where_is:pancakes_house"

>> :'xmlns:xsi'.to_s
=> "xmlns:xsi"
```

Comment: nope weird, none of these cases work, even when just using a string with a colon in it.  As soon as I remove the colon it works just fine...Is there some way to escape the colon?

Comment: @Ryan: What does "not work" mean in this case? An exception? Incorrect output? No output?

Comment: ahh sorry! i should have clarified! The output is there, no exception, it's just incorrect.  It reads: <AddDealRequest> when it should read: <AddDealRequest xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

Comment: @Ryan: What if you toss a `nocolon => 'stuff'` into the mix? Will it give you `<AddDealRequest nocolon="stuff">`? Which version of builder are you using? Both string and quote symbol forms are working for me.

Comment: yeah it works perfectly if there is no colon. i have a rails 3 app but i am using builder 2.1.2

Comment: @Ryan: Any chance of upgrading to builder 3? I've been experimenting with builder-3 in a Rails3 console and the above approaches work fine.

Comment: not really. it seems rails 3.0.0 depends on builder 2.1.2. argh!

Comment: @Ryan: 2.1.2 explicitly or > 2.1.2? Which version of Ruby?

Comment: I ask about the Ruby version because I've been poking around the commit logs at https://github.com/jimweirich/builder and a 1.9 patch seems to be the most recent thing going on. I also don't see anything obvious in the source that would have a problem with colons.

Comment: hmm, weirder yet I it works fine in chrome, but doesn't show up in firefox.

Comment: @Ryan: What if you dump the XML to a text file and look at that with a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

*Rather than expect anyone to read through all the comments in the earliest answer, I'll just post the outcome here:*

Firefox doesn't display the `xmlns` attribute (at least not when it matches a default). If you view the source (Ctrl+U) or use Chrome as your browser, you'll see that the missing attributes are appearing in the xml output.

Comment: Indeed, thank you!

Was just wondering why it wasn't showing the xmlns:xxx attribute in Firefox!